# How do I combine these two conditionals?

Tags: conditional-tags

I'm using two conditionals, which I want to combine into one:

```
if ( !is_page(56) )
  if ( !is_404() ) {
 // Do something.
 }
```

The intent is 'if it's not page 56 or a 404, do something'.

I haven't found a way to combine them without it either not working or triggering an 'unexpected '||'' error.

I suspect it's because I don't know enough to correctly position the brackets.

Comment: This site's for WP development, your question is about starting PHP, I recommend looking up if statement syntax and conditional statements on php.net

Comment: @ Tom J Nowell... I read a lot before posting, and I'm appreciative of the help received. Although I've no desire to generate friction, I'm surprised at the frequency of 'don't do that' comments. I can appreciate the desire for 'focused useful resource', but it's not a perfect world - and if a question is considered rather than just lazy, it's easier (and perhaps more helpful) to just ignore it rather than 'step-in' (with or without open admonishment). :-)

Comment: Here's the remainder of my comment above... This isn't a question about starting php, but using it in WP - and Vint's answer (in providing something of genuine worth) is more useful than an off-topic hold. Shame on you, for being heavy-handed rather than noble.

Comment: To clarify... rather than myself, I'm more bothered about others who've been admonished when asking something they genuinely felt acceptable. I'd read some such examples (and subsequent bemusement and disagreement in the comments, not just by the OP) yesterday, just prior to posting my question, hence my sensitivity to 'put on hold'. Tom's comment is a helpful suggestion, although not something with which I fully concur.

Comment: We have a well defined scope, if your question doesn't fit into it then it'll be closed as off topic. You weren't admonished. Tbh this question would have been better on Stack Overflow, just because it happens to be in a WP theme doesn't change that no WP knowledge is necessary to answer it.

If you disagree we have a mechanism for changing and deciding how the site is ran and what is in and what is out of scope by raising it on this stacks meta site

Comment: @Tom J Nowell... I'm not sure the scope is 'well defined'. In 'how to ask', the guidance of 'Is your question about WordPress?' doesn't account for things which, although they may be php/css/html/other, are the subject of a question being asked by posters wanting to use them in their WP install and who don't know enough to determine whether the issue will be regarded as 'generic' by more experienced users.

Comment: ... continued...  People come here to receive and give help... and toward that more care shown toward trying to help 'inexperienced learners' rather than simply haughtily closing things is probably a genuinely good thing. For many, venturing onto other parts of Stack isn't an easy thing to do. And, in closing, I'll repeat my original point that my gripe isn't about closing my question, but refers to the seemingly frequent issue of how posts are closed and how doing so doesn't help. It's not a perfect world, and hence 'some unintentioned pollution of the pool' should be expected and tolerated.

Comment: we have an open process via https://meta.wordpress.stackexchange.com , comments are not the way to enact change on this site, the scope is very clear and if you disagree or wish to change them, then that's the place to go

Comment: @Tom J Nowell... I note your point. :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Very easy -

```
if ( !is_page(56)&&!is_404())
  // Do something.
}
```

Regards,

Vinit Patil.

Comment: Thanks. I hadn't thought about 'and'... my brain was thinking 'if it's not page 56 OR a 404'. :-)